# Annotating ggplot2 by wrapping points in a box

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that looks like this (code for generating it below):

[image: Movement of bits using one-at-a-time-hashing]

I wonder if there is an easy way to make it look like this:

[image: Highlighted input bytes]

i.e., I would like to highlight eight positions in four rows by putting a box around them.

If you are interested, the plot shows how bits are moving using the one-at-a-time hash function on four bytes, so I want to highlight the four input-bytes. I overlay different bit-patterns in various other plots, showing how different bits depend on other bits in parameters of the function and on the input bits. So I have to generate several versions of the same plot, and therefore I would much prefer not to have to annotate a PDF file for each plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

oaat_hash_positions <- function(bit) {
  op_1 <- function(pos, step, bit) {
    updated_pos <- outer(pos, c(10, 0), FUN = '+')  %>% as.vector() %>% unique()
    tibble(bit = bit, x = step - 1, y = pos, xend = step, yend = updated_pos) %>%
      filter(y >= 0 & y < 32 & yend >= 0 & yend < 31)
  }
  op_2 <- function(pos, step, bit) {
    updated_pos <- outer(pos, c(0, -6), FUN = '+')  %>% as.vector() %>% unique()
    tibble(bit = bit, x = step - 1, y = pos, xend = step, yend = updated_pos) %>%
      filter(y >= 0 & y < 32 & yend >= 0 & yend < 31)
  }
  final_op_1 <- function(pos, step, bit) {
    updated_pos <- outer(pos, c(0, 3), FUN = '+')  %>% as.vector() %>% unique()
    tibble(bit = bit, x = step - 1, y = pos, xend = step, yend = updated_pos) %>%
      filter(y >= 0 & y < 32 & yend >= 0 & yend < 31)
  }
  final_op_2 <- function(pos, step, bit) {
    updated_pos <- outer(pos, c(0, -11), FUN = '+')  %>% as.vector() %>% unique()
    tibble(bit = bit, x = step - 1, y = pos, xend = step, yend = updated_pos) %>%
      filter(y >= 0 & y < 32 & yend >= 0 & yend < 31)
  }
  final_op_3 <- function(pos, step, bit) {
    updated_pos <- outer(pos, c(0, 15), FUN = '+')  %>% as.vector() %>% unique()
    tibble(bit = bit, x = step - 1, y = pos, xend = step, yend = updated_pos) %>%
      filter(y >= 0 & y < 32 & yend >= 0 & yend < 31)
  }

  operation_1 <- map(bit,              ~ op_1(.x, step = 1, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()
  operation_2 <- map(operation_1$yend, ~ op_2(.x, step = 2, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()
  operation_3 <- map(operation_2$yend, ~ op_1(.x, step = 3, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()
  operation_4 <- map(operation_3$yend, ~ op_2(.x, step = 4, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()
  operation_5 <- map(operation_4$yend, ~ op_1(.x, step = 5, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()
  operation_6 <- map(operation_5$yend, ~ op_2(.x, step = 6, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()
  operation_7 <- map(operation_6$yend, ~ op_1(.x, step = 7, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()
  operation_8 <- map(operation_7$yend, ~ op_2(.x, step = 8, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()

  operation_9 <-  map(operation_8$yend,  ~ final_op_1(.x, step = 9, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()
  operation_10 <- map(operation_9$yend,  ~ final_op_2(.x, step = 10, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()
  operation_11 <- map(operation_10$yend, ~ final_op_3(.x, step = 11, bit = bit)) %>% bind_rows()

  rbind(operation_1, operation_2,
        operation_3, operation_4,
        operation_5, operation_6,
        operation_7, operation_8,
        operation_9, operation_10, operation_11)
}
bit_movement <- do.call(rbind, lapply(0:31, oaat_hash_positions))

plot_bitmovement <- function(bm_segs) {
  ggplot(bm_segs, aes(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    xend = xend,
    yend = yend)
  ) +
    geom_segment(colour = "grey") +
    geom_point(colour = "grey") +
    geom_point(aes(x = xend, y = yend), colour = "grey") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:31, labels = 1:32) +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none"
    ) + ylab("Bit-position") + xlab("Operation")
}

plot_bitmovement(bit_movement)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `geom_rect` with no fill to place a border around those points. I'm not familiar with the context you're working in, so there may be some things you need to adjust here. I added arguments to the function so you can supply a vector of operation values and positions to highlight, plus a value of how much padding to put around the box.

I didn't address the fact that your breaks and labels are offset by 1—like I said, that's probably something context-specific that you'll want to fix.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# omitting function that creates bitmovement data

plot_bitmovement <- function(bm_segs, hilite_op, hilite_pos, box_pad = 0.4) {
  hilite <- tibble(x = hilite_op, ymin = min(hilite_pos), ymax = max(hilite_pos))

  ggplot(bm_segs, aes(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    xend = xend,
    yend = yend)
  ) +
    geom_segment(colour = "grey") +
    geom_point(colour = "grey") +
    geom_point(aes(x = xend, y = yend), colour = "grey") +
  # add hilite box #########
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = x - box_pad, 
                  xmax = x + box_pad, 
                  ymin = ymin - box_pad, 
                  ymax = ymax + box_pad), 
              data = hilite, color = "black", fill = "transparent", inherit.aes = F) +
  ##########################
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:31, labels = 1:32) +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none"
    ) + ylab("Bit-position") + xlab("Operation")
}

hilite_x <- seq(0, 6, by = 2)
hilite_y <- 1:8

plot_bitmovement(bit_movement, hilite_x, hilite_y)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks, that looks very much like what I need!